# AngularJS: how to preventDefault() of an event after promise completes?

Tags: events, angularjs, promise, angularjs-routing

I have some code like this:

```js
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, newPath, oldPath) {

    // Do some sync checks
    if (!$scope.isPageAllowed($location.path()))
    {
        // Prevent default for some reason
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

When I trying to resolve `promises` like this:

```js
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, newPath, oldPath) {

    // Do some async checks
    $scope.fooPromises().then(function (data) {

         // Prevent default for some reason when promises resolved (only if resolved)
         event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I got successfull `event` (because of async execution) and after a while prevented `event` when `promises` are resolved.

Is there a way to link `event` with my `promises`, so it would be prevented exactly after promises being resolved and not streight after function end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, this won't work :-).  Events are purely synchronous.

You're looking for $route.resolve.  Asynchronous resolution/rejection of routes, to give a controller data or just to check something.

http://www.egghead.io/video/Kr1qZ8Ik9G8

Comment: Thanks for your response @andy-joslin, I'd found this solution but there is problem with location. When I reject promise, no action fired, as expected, but URL are still changed. So that's the reason I am looking at $locationChangeStart event - it fires exactly before location path changed so I could prevent URL from visual changes (no flickering). If there Is a case when reject resolve can also prevent URL changes - your help will be much appreciated. (Sorry for bad English if so)

Comment: Hi Felikz, sorry for lateness.  The $routeChangeError event will give you the previous and attempted route objects as parameters.  You can get the previous route's path from the previous route object and redirect the user back to there using `$location.path()`, and display an error.

Comment: already tryed it. This objects contains exact `data` of .when('/path/:maybe_with_params', { /* `data` */ }) which does not contains exact `path` :(

Also tryied $locationChangeSuccess event to handle this. But it returns `absolute url` which is a problem to parse it (very dirty way, imho)